# Load new data into calling form when the called form is closed

Tags: c#, .net, forms

How can I load new data into calling form when the called form is closed?

For example,
I have 2 form:

---

form A and form B

form A has combobox (which has listitems "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid" =>the listitem comes from database )

form A calls form B (show dialog)

In form B, I add new city for example "London"

when I close form B, I want combobox in form A to load city data again

(now, the list contains "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid", "London")

How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of doing this. Here is one of the ways.

Pass FormA as a parameter to the FormB constructor.

In FormB Class

```
private FormA parentFormA;

public FormB(FormA myFormA)
{
    parentFormA = myFormA;
}

Private void FormB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //parentFormA.UpdateCityData(parameter)
}
```

In FormA Open FormB as below

```
FormB formB = new FormB(this);
formB.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make form B into you own class with a property. Then you can use it in form A by just getting the NewCity value after ShowDialog is finished.

```
class CityAdderForm : Form
{
    public string NewCity { get; set; }


    private void CityAdderForm _FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        NewCity = // ... any logic that will set the NewCity property.
    }
}
```